# After changing my minecraft username I can't play on any of my servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When I changed my Minecraft name I logged out of my launcher and relogged.

When I tried to connect to a server, it said : *"Not authenticated with Minecraft.net"*

Any help ?[image]

Comment: I've heard of this problem a lot before, but relogging usually fixes it. Try again, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Try completely logging out and relaunching the launcher. It should update the new username when loading.